# How do I populate Laravel/Blade checkboxes from json in a db

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

Laravel is great that it auto populates the fields for you on an edit form. However i seem to be having bother getting this to work for checkboxes.

I have a list of disciplines that get stored as a json array in the database like so `["FULL_CONTACT","K1"]`

How do I get these to display as checked in the form?

```
{!! Form::model($official, array('method' => 'put', 'route' => ['officials.update', $official->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-lg-3 control-label">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9 controls">
            {!! Form::text('first_name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'max-length' => '50', 'required')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <label class="checkbox">
        {!! Form::checkbox('disciplines[]', null) !!} Full Contact
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        {!! Form::checkbox('disciplines[]', null) !!} Low Kick
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
        {!! Form::checkbox('disciplines[]', null) !!} K1
    </label>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ Form::checkbox('disciplines[]', 'Low Kick', true) }}
```

this will generate following html

```
  <input checked="checked" name="disciplines[]" type="checkbox" value="Low Kick">
```

Answer (score 0):

Form::checkbox's arguments are 
    `Form::checkbox($name, $value, $checked, $options)`

You can use @foreach loop to display all the checkboxs, for example:

```
@foreach($disciplines as $discipline)
    {!! Form::checkbox('disciplines[]', $discipline, null) !!} label
@endforeach`
```

Comment: I have them hard coded for design positioning purposes so i cant really loop through them

Comment: @PeterSmith then you can pass the value into the second argument of the `Form::checkbox()`, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: if the value of the check box is in the array back from the DB i want it to be checked